# Git Authentication Failure Spring Cloud config store

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config-server

We are configuring spring cloud config server and below is how my application properties look:

```
server.port=8080
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/myorganization/config-store.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths={application}
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.skipSslValidation=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.ignore-local-ssh-settings=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=MyUser
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=MyPassword
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=develop
spring.application.name=config-server
spring.security.user.name=root
spring.security.user.password=password
```

I am able to login to the github url i.e. https://github.com/myorganization/config-store.git using the username MyUser and password MyPassword as per above properties but when i am trying to start my config server using: ./mvnw spring-boot:run i am getting the below error:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/myorganization/config-store.git: not authorized
```

i have tried out many things but running out of any ideas now, would appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Beginning August 13, 2021, we will no longer accept account passwords when authenticating Git operations on GitHub.com.

From : https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

Thx to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70443213/592355

For [Github Enterprise Server](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github), our options (also) are limited, but considered secure & well documented:

> #### Authenticating with the API
>
> You can authenticate with the API in different ways.
> ...
>
> - Personal access tokens (-> 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69663073/592355, 2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70580891/592355 ?)
> - OAuth Apps...
> - GitHub Apps...
>
> #### Authenticating with the command line
>
> ...
>
> - HTTPS ...
> - SSH ...

---

When SSH, for the [spring-cloud](/questions/tagged/spring-cloud)-end:

Use "local ssh environment" or see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_git_ssh_configuration_using_properties

Answer (score 3):

The use of username and password to do git operations on GitHub is deprecated and it no longer works, as described [here](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/).

You should generate a **Personal Access Token**, follow [the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) to do it. Then you can add the token to the spring configuration as it was you password:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=<yourusername>
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=<yourtoken>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using github and the new [fine grained access token](https://github.com/settings/personal-access-tokens/new) generated from github. In that case the username and password both must be set to the same token generated.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-service
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/UserName/PrivateRepo
          username: github_fine_access_token_xxxx
          password: github_fine_access_token_xxxx
```

You can also use environment variables here